# What can be inferred from a short multivariate time series?

Tags: time-series, pca, multivariate-analysis, change-point

I have annual observations of 24 variables over 10 years, and I would like to identify evidence of structural change (regime shift). The data pertain to university enrollment & spending, so I expect the variables to be trend stationary and I'm looking for shifts in the linear trends.

My concern is the number of observations seems far too small to identify a regime shift with any certitude, but I hope there's a way to compensate using the large number of variables. Many of the variables are highly correlated so I've looked into PCA for dimensionality reduction, but then I'm unsure how to evaluate statistical certainty (for example with the Chow test).

A standardized version of the data can be found here as a CSV file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7z9b5n5exq2j6t5/standardized.csv?dl=0

Edit: I'm looking for general methods which could be useful in such a case, not an analysis of this data file specifically (which was included only upon request).

Comment: What are the explained variances of PCA components?

Comment: Am I assuming correctly that you have annual data (i.e., 10 data points)?

Comment: Yes, I have ten consecutive annual data points. The first two principal components account for 60% and 15% of the variance, respectively.

Comment: which series is the dependent series ?

Comment: There is no clear dependent series; all datapoints are simply annual figures for one university, e.g. "Total enrollment" or "Salary outlays of full-time instructional faculty."

Answer (score 1):

The problem you face is twofold: 1 . you have to find that subset of 19 predictors which best "relates" to the series of interest. and 2. for that subset of series find out what contemporaneous and lag structure are needed for each of the selected candidates AND then find out (discover) via Intervention Detection procedures if any Pulses/Level Shifts/Trend Changes can be identified . Why don't you post your data and I fill try and help you. Others might also try using their own expertise/software. Your 10 observations will present a challenge both to me and I am sure other readers.

UPON RECEIPT OF YOUR DATA:

These 23 characteristics. each with 10 values were submitted to AUTOBOX for expert time series analysis to determine  the underlying equation and exceptional activity (structural changes). Your post requesting structural change/regime shift can only be answered by forming an ARIMA equation and then identifying four kinds of interventions (Pulses/Level Shifts/Seasonal Pulses and Local Time trends). With 10 values AUTOBOX was restricted to just searching for Pulses. I have saved a zip file (containing just 18 of the 23 as 5 had no Interventions Detected ) named  http://www.autobox.com/stack/23.zip . In general structural shifts can be due to a  possible changes in  model parameters over time ,  changes in error variance over time or a changes in either level or slope. A pulse is an instantaneous change in level.

Comment: I'm concerned that allowing for lag structure (and intervention analysis) introduces far too many parameters for this system. Are there no linear methods that can be useful here? Ultimately I'd like a methodology which could be applied to datasets from other institutions.

Comment: one can restrict the number of parameters. methodology and software is not restricted to what is being analyzed. Load the data and we will see what we will see. Perhaps we will see nothing !

Comment: I included a link to the standardized data in my original post.

Comment: Thank you for your analysis! So, you fit an ARIMA model to the univariate time series and used it to detect pulses. It seems that at t=3 and t=6, pulses were detected in several of the variables, although the presence of correlated variables might complicate the significance. Perhaps I can try a similar analysis with de-correlated variables with PCA or factor analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your data and ran PCA. It came back with 9 components. Note, that the rank of your matrix is 9, not 10. There's got to be some linear dependencies, which you didn't reveal to us. We don't know what are your columns, maybe some columns are totals of subsets of other columns etc.

Anyhow, take look at the charts below. The top one shows the series over time, and the bottom shows 9 PCA components. From the top chart you can see that several series seem to be growing, while a few are stationary.

The bottom shart shows that only the first PCA component is growing, and it explains 60% of the variation. The others don't seem to be changing much. You can run statistical tests if you wish, but it's pointless in my opinion given the sample size. You won't be able to squeeze out more information than from the plots. There is no sign of structural break. You will not be able to prove it for overall data set. You may try to go after one or two series, based on the domain knowledge, of course. However, I doubt that you'll get anything. None of the PCA components are obviously breaking here.

[image]

MATLAB Code

```
[coeff,score,latent,tsquared,explained,mu] = pca(standardized);

subplot(2,1,1)
plot(standardized)
title 'Series'
legend('location','Best')

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(score)
title 'PCA components'
legend('location','Best')

rank(standardized)
explained
```

OUTPUT

```
ans =

     9

explained =

   60.8074
   13.8883
    7.9533
    6.0521
    4.5944
    3.5775
    1.8449
    0.8761
    0.4060
```

Comment: If there were an obvious structural break in one of the principal components, perhaps a dramatic change in an inferred slope, what statistical test could be used? What if the break occurs in a PC with a smaller explained variance?

Comment: There's a number of ways to test for a structural break, e.g. Chow's parameter constancy test. With 10 time points all the statistical tests will have a dubious value.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I suspected.

One naive follow-up question: is it possible, despite having only ten time points, to combine multiple dubious statistical inferences into one stronger result? That is, if I suspect a break at t=3 in several variables, can I combine them for greater certainty? Or is that what PCA/FA is for?

Comment: @MarcKjerland, with $t=3$ is that you can't use time series models. How are you going to estimate a time series model on 3 points? One thing you could try is to look at the PCA components other than #1, which appear to be stationary, and run Chow test or ANOVA to see if the mean has changes. Again, it's only 3 points, the power of a test will be very weak.

Comment: @Marc, you could use any test you like and get a hypothetical breakpoint for each time series. Maybe each of them separately would have a large p-value, but imagine that you have 100 time series and for *all of them* the test reports a breakpoint at t=3. Then this is already significant by itself. So yes, one certainly can "combine multiple dubious statistical inferences into one stronger result". Note that you would need to assume independence of your time series though.